# How to find word count in each git commit in a repository's history?

Tags: git, perl, sed, commit

This is about word counts, but I guess it's also about running any program across all git commits in a repository. I am doing a writing project, and realized late that I wanted to generate the word count programmatically after each commit. Only for tex files. But then, how to get the counts for the life of the project? I could not find a simple way to do it, so that is what I am asking.

My solution was to automate the manual process of checking out a branch for each individual commit in the life of the project, and running my little shell/sed/perl scripts to get the date and the word count:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use App::gh::Git;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(capture);

my $repo = Git->repository( Directory => '/home/amiri/MyProject/.git' );
my @commits
    = reverse $repo->command( 'rev-list', '--all', '--date', 'short' );

my $command
    = qq{find /home/amiri/MyProject -name "*.tex" | xargs wc -w | grep total | sed 's/[a-zA-Z[:space:]]//g'};

my $command2
    = q{git log | grep "Date:" | sed -n 1p | perl -pi -e "s/^Date:\s+//g" | perl -pi -e "s/2011 -\d+$/UTC 2011/g"};

for my $commit (@commits) {
    $repo->command( "checkout", "-b", "$commit", "$commit" );
    my $count = capture($command);
    my $date  = capture($command2);
    chomp $date;
    say "$date,$count";
    $repo->command( "checkout", "master" );
    $repo->command( 'branch', "-d", $commit );
}
```

So, this works, but I can't help but feel there's a better way to do it? It seems a little icky.

Comment: You could adapt [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9141855/635608) to do that pretty easily. (Not my answer to that question, it's closer to your approach, and not nearly as good.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted something easier to implement, and don't mind being a little suboptimal and kludgy, you could do this:

```
for commit in `git rev-list --all`; do
    git log -n 1 --pretty=%ad $commit
    git archive $commit | tar -x -O | wc -w
done
```

This is way shorter than what you have, and I suspect it might also be faster, because it avoids having to check out files to disk just to read them again to count words. (To restrict it only to certain files, you can pass them as additional arguments to `git archive`, and note that you can get a list of all files in a given commit with `git ls-tree -r --name-only <commit>`.)

The `git log` line just prints the commit date. If you want more, have a look at `man git-log` for a description of the things you can do - essentially there are tons of placeholders like `%ad` for author date, `%s` for commit subject, and so on. The next line does the work. `git archive` is designed for packing up a given tree into a tar/zip for distribution; we just immediately untar it and count the words. (Obviously you can tweak the output format, and substitute in your own counting mechanism for `wc -w` if desired.)

This is already pretty fast - on a several-year-old laptop it took about a quarter second per commit in a repo with a 20MB work tree.

Of course, if you really really care about performance, probably the absolute *fastest* method would be to, for each commit, walk the tree, summing word counts over blobs, and storing word counts for each blob so that you don't have to recount them. This is a heck of a lot more work to implement, though. Pseudocode might look like this:

```
word_counts(range)
    for (commit in `git rev-list <range>`)
        sum = 0
        for (blob in second_field_of(`git ls-tree -r commit`))
            if (!counts[blob])
                counts[blob] = word_count(`git cat-file blob`)
             total_count += counts[blob]
         print pretty_format(commit), total_count

 pretty_format(commit)
     return `git log -n 1 --pretty=... commit`
```

This avoids any unnecessary intermediate steps, and further optimizes by avoiding having to re-read any unchanged files. In tiny repositories that might not be a big deal, but in larger repos it's a huge deal - imagine a 20MB repo where commits on average touch files of total size 20KB.

Comment: Thanks for the bash loop. I was looking for a git-contained answer, and you delivered, Jefromi!

Answer (score 0):

Extending @cascabel's answer, I recently needed to do a word count on MS Word documents in an archive. Took me a while to figure out, so here it is, extendible to any other type of binary and count...

```
TMPDIR=/tmp/a
mkdir $TMPDIR 2> /dev/null
for commit in `git rev-list --all`; do
    git log -n 1 --pretty=%ad $commit
    git archive $commit | (cd $TMPDIR ; rm *; tar -x '*.docx'; pandoc -t plain * | wc -w ) 2>/dev/null
done
```